# Fetching the data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

I am trying to draw a chart fetching data from a Web Api. I can see some data is getting through   but I still can not get the chart drawn. Pls let me know if I am doing something wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './main.styles.scss';
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3500/stock/app/RY`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.webApiData;
}

class Main extends Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const chart = createChart(this.ref.current, {
      width: 1400,
      height: 550,
      timeScale: {
        timeVisible: true,
        secondsVisible: false,
      },
    });

    const candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries();

    const chartData = getData().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      candleSeries.setData(data);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="trading">
          <div className="box one">1</div>
          <div className="box two" ref={this.ref}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Here is the data on the console.log
[image]

Here is the error I am getting
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the format of the `time` attribute is not in the correct style.
It should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` style.

For example, you can try

```
const chartData = getData().then((data) => {
   console.log(data);
   candleSeries.setData(data.map((sD) => {
       return {time: `${sD.time.year}-${sD.month > 9 ? sD.month : `0${sD.time.month}`}-${sD.day > 9 ? sD.day : `0${sD.day}`}`, ...sD}
   }));
});
```

Comment: I think you're missing = after the getData function name.

Comment: The function format should be ```export const getData = async (url) => { /* ... */ }```

Comment: Downgrading the version of ```lightweight-charts``` to 3.0.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `time` format is incorrect. It should be a date string.

From the candlestick chart [docs](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/master/docs/candlestick-series.md):

> Each item of the candlestick series is either an OHLC or a whitespace item.

So `time` must be in the following format.

```
const ohlcItem = {
    time: '2018-06-25',
    open: 10,
    high: 12,
    low: 9,
    close: 11,
};
```

OR

```
// note it might be any type of series here
const series = chart.addHistogramSeries();

series.setData([
    { time: '2018-12-01', value: 32.51 },
    { time: '2018-12-02', value: 31.11 },
    { time: '2018-12-03', value: 27.02 },
    { time: '2018-12-04' }, // whitespace
    { time: '2018-12-05' }, // whitespace
    { time: '2018-12-06' }, // whitespace
    { time: '2018-12-07' }, // whitespace
    { time: '2018-12-08', value: 23.92 },
    { time: '2018-12-09', value: 22.68 },
    { time: '2018-12-10', value: 22.67 },
    { time: '2018-12-11', value: 27.57 },
    { time: '2018-12-12', value: 24.11 },
    { time: '2018-12-13', value: 30.74 },
]);
```

Comment: you are absolutely right but here is the problem. I am providing the right format but for some reason it is converted to the one that you see on the screen shot

Comment: @JohnJohn Can you create a codesandbox with the data?